# Why is curvature quadratic?

Tags: optimization, curvature

In my textbook, it describes the hessian being the local quadratic of the optimization landscape. The hessian is synonymous with curvature.

I'm wondering why curvature is quadratic?

Comment: Curvature is related to the osculating circle, which is a second-degree curve.

Comment: Fascinating. Thanks for the comment. Do you have a link to learn more?

Comment: To me, the quadratic model is another way to get the local basin of attraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Hessian is not synonymous with curvature. The quadratic (involving Hessian) is the lowest order term in a multivariate Taylor series expansion which captures any curvature. Higher order terms than quadratic (Hessian) are not usually used in optimization.  But higher order methods can be used in optimization, and sometimes are.

Comment: `is the lowest order term in a multivariate Taylor series expansion` -- expansion of what?

Comment: Of the objective function for unconstrained problems, or perhaps of the Lagrangian (see section 4.2 of http://mat.gsia.cmu.edu/classes/QUANT/NOTES/chap4.pdf ) for constrained problems.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the link. Why does this approximation of the function help us with determining a local minima?

Comment: Essentially because of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions .But that connection won't be obvious without more study.

Comment: Fascinating. Thanks for all the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Slope is obtained by first differentiation... like with differential  operator $D$. Curvature is obtained by second  differentiation, like with the operator $D^2$.

Second order terms and their products like $rt-s^2$ in Hessian vanish for flat planes and the like. It is positive for positive (double or Gauss) curvature surfaces and negative for negative curvature surfaces. Hessian indicates sign of curvature.

Comment: What is a differential operator?

Comment: In differential equations notation we write $ Dy, D^2y $ for $y^{'},\, y^{''}$

Comment: Interesting. I'm guessing it an operator on a vector space that spits out a number (because that's what an operator is defined in linear algebra). I'm not sure how differential modifies that or if that's just a cosmetic thing

Comment: http://www.codecogs.com/library/maths/calculus/differential/the-d-operator.php#sec10                                                                        
 For second order diffrl equns with const coefficients , somewhat like quadratic equation solution